# Is it possible to have multiple checkbox values on one column in igGrid of ignite ui/infragistics using razor MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, infragistics, ignite-ui

So Im using infragistics on my gridview, and the logic is I have single to multiple relationship on my data, I want to implement the connection of that logic on my igGrid. I cant find a way to do it, so I just wanted to know if it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little vague, but what I'm getting from the title is that you want to render multiple checkboxes inside a single column, that are bound to multiple properties in your data. This is possible using a column template:

1. Bind the column to one of the properties.
2. Have the other properties available in the client data.
3. Construct the [column template](http://www.igniteui.com/help/api/2016.1/ui.iggrid#options:columns.template) to render a checkbox in the cell for each property.
4. If you have an array under one property, then again use templating to render all of them.
5. You will also have to add handlers to the change events of the checkboxes.

An example with array would be:

```
column.For(x => x.Prop)
      .HeaderText("Property")
      .DataType("object")
      .Template("{{each ${Prop} }}<input type='checkbox' checked='${Prop.PropValue} /> | {{/each}}");
```

An example with multiple top level properties:

```
column.For(x => x.Prop1)
      .HeaderText("Property")
      .DataType("object")
      .Template("<input type='checkbox' checked='${Prop1} /> | <input type='checkbox' checked='${Prop2} /> | <input type='checkbox' checked='${Prop3} />");
```